# JsonObject set in HashMap

Tags: android

I want to first get particuler data from JsonObject then  i also want to set that JsonObject as parallel data.   I think it is possible with HashMap. But i do not know how to set data as  parallel JsonObject. And How to use ? 
Please Help me.

I want to each name with each own JsonObject.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     String name = json.optString("username");
     list.add(json);
}
```

Comment: Didn't get what you want to do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this
You declare `global` variable

```
     private HashMap<String, JSONObject> mHashMap;
      @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.admin_frag_update_driver, container, false);
            mHashMap = new HashMap<String, JSONObject>();
}

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     String name = json.optString("username");
     list.add(json);
mHashMap.put(name , object);
}

JSONObject object = mHashMap.get(name );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will help

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(INTEREST_ACCEPT_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        interestaccept = jsonObj.getJSONArray(INTEREST_ACCEPT);

                        for (int i = 0; i < interestaccept.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = interestaccept.getJSONObject(i);
                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(INTERESTACCEPT_USER_ID, c.getString(INTERESTACCEPT_USER_ID));
                            map.put(INTEREST_ACCEPT_NAME,c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_NAME));
                            map.put(INTEREST_ACCEPT_PROFILE, c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_PROFILE));
                            map.put(INTEREST_ACCEPT_IMAGE, c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_IMAGE));
                            map.put(INTEREST_ACCEPT_CAST, c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_CAST));
                            map.put(INTEREST_ACCEPT_AGE, c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_AGE)+" years");
                            map.put(INTEREST_ACCEPT_LOCATION, c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_LOCATION));
                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            data.add(map);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }
                return data;
```